# New Relic not fully working on rails 4 app using turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, newrelic, turbolinks

I'm trying to get New Relic fully working in my RoR4 app. But fail to get subsequent page loads via turbolinks to be tracked as the new relic Javascript is included into the  of the page and therefore not sending any logging information to New Relic.

Has anyone of you an idea how I could move the New Relic JS into the  or use some JS event to trigger a new relic log ping using the turbolinks events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to track your loads occurring through turbolinks in Rails 4 using New Relic's browser monitoring, the best method for this is to use the [beta AJAX timing feature](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/new-relic-browser/ajax-dashboard). You can [enable AJAX timing](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/new-relic-browser/browser-settings#enabling) on the Browser settings page for the application. If you're using a Ruby agent version earlier than 3.7.0.177, you may need to first [upgrade your agent](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/ruby) to be compatible with the browser beta features.